# The collectionViewLayout won't appear

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, collectionview

So, I made gxcci layout and it won't appear in my collectionView which is PhotoStreamController, even though I've connected everything already because in my other project.Everything runs perfectly. But the difference with the other one is im using collectionView Controller and right now I'm using ControllerView and CollectionView. Thanks in Advance

**GxcciLayout**

```
class GxcciLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

var delegate: GxcciLayoutDelegate!
var numberOfColumns = 2
var cellPadding : CGFloat = 1

private var cache = [GxcciLayoutAttributes]()
private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
private var contentWidth: CGFloat {
    let insets = collectionView!.contentInset
    return collectionView!.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
}

override class var layoutAttributesClass: AnyClass {
    return GxcciLayoutAttributes.self
}
```

and here is the controller page

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PhotoStreamController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var PhotoStreamCollection: UICollectionView!

override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}

var photos = Photo.allPhotos()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let layout = self.PhotoStreamCollection.collectionViewLayout as? GxcciLayout {
    layout.delegate = self    
}
}
```